# How to link the TOC to header names (in HTML view)?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a document in HTML format. One of the elements is an automatically generated Table of Contents which is all fine except that the links point to automatically generated labels, instead of header names:

```
file:///C:/mydoc.htm#_Toc403724331
```

(this link would later be visible in production as `http://server.example.com/mydoc.htm#_Toc403724331`)

Since I would like to further reuse the links in a portable way (by, for instance, sending to someone a link to a section of my page) I would very much prefer less mutable (and better looking) links, something like

```
file:///C:/mydoc.htm#the_title_of_a_section
```

(where `_Toc403724331` actually points to, and which would later, per above, turn into `http://server.example.com/mydoc.htm#the_title_of_a_section`)

Is this something which is doable? (I did not find anything suitable in custom TOCs properties). I do not care about the format of the link, provided it does not change upon TOC rebuild and carries information about the header of the section)

Comment: As far as I can tell, Word *always* generates internal bookmark names for the ToC links. Even if you select a heading and create a bookmark, Word generates its own and uses it in the ToC. Which suggests that the simplest thing you could do would be to do a bulk find/replace, changing each generated bookmark, wherever it occurs, to the HTML bookmark that you want. To have a valid and informative HTML bookmark I think you will in any case have to transform your headings "by hand", so it's then really a question of how to match WOrd's bookmarks with yours and how to do a batch substitution.

Comment: @bibadia: Thanks, I was afraid that this would be the case. I already started to think about a way to convert the data with `BeautifulSoup`in Python but it is not an obvious exercise.